# How to improve performance in Creating and populating Excel

Tags: .net, asp.net, excel

I am generating an Excel document dynamically and populating it with more than 200,000 records. Then I need to upload the file to another server.

For the above functionality, I just wrote the code in the code behind. It is taking 20-30 mininutes to see the populated excel document though, and the same while uploading.

How can I speed up this process? Please help.

HERE is my CODE

Private Sub FillDataRows(ByVal ws As Worksheet)
        Dim rowcount As Integer = 7
        Dim colcount As Integer = 1
        Dim rowscount As Integer

```
    For Each dr As DataRow In dsCostUsage.Tables(0).Rows
        colcount = 1
        Dim items As Object() = dr.ItemArray
        For Each item As Object In items
            Dim nextItem As String = ""
             nextItem = item.ToString()
             DirectCast(ws.Cells(rowcount, colcount), Range).Value2 = nextItem
            colcount += 1
        Next
        rowcount += 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide some code so we can see where you're at.

Answer (score 3):

Your use of Excel automation from ASP.NET is NOT supported according to [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;q257757#kb2) .

For generating Excel in ASP.NET you can use a free library called [OpenXML 2.0 from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854.aspx).

Comment: I Used as       below                                                                   Dim App As New Application
        Dim workbook As Workbook = App.Workbooks.Add()
        Dim worksheet As Worksheet = workbook.Worksheets(1)

Comment: I am creating excel and populating records from dataset