# reading large datasets and write to excel

Tags: asp.net, excel, dataset

I am reading dataset which is having 50k records and fill them in excel without using webservice.i am looping all the records as

```
For Each dr As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
```

This is taking 20 min to loop through all the records an fill excel.

Is there anyway that we can use threading, and how we can implement it to fill the excel faster?

Comment: Please don't post duplicate questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206580/how-to-improve-performance-in-creating-and-populating-excel

Answer (score 0):

if you are using .net Framework 4.0 then try PLINQ's  Parallel.ForEach to utilize all processors together..